# Why does the "schema" disappear from the "responses" object when importing an OpenAPI definition?

Tags: azure-api-management, openapi

I can successfully import the following OpenAPI definition into Azure API Management.

However, when I export the OpenAPI definition, the "schema" name has been removed from the "responses" object. As a result, developers in my portal are not shown a schema or example for this operation.

My API definition is valid and functions correctly if added to [the official editor](https://editor.swagger.io//#/).

How can I prevent the schema from being stripped out?

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Foo",
    "description": "Foo",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "host": "example.org",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/foo": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "List all foo.",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success.",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "example": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "An example."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem seems to occur when the definition lacks a "produces" name, in either the root object, or in the operation object.

For example, the following definition should import successfully, and then export without the "schema" being stripped away. Note that the "produces" name has been added to the root object, in between "schemes" and "paths"

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Foo",
    "description": "Foo",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "host": "example.org",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "produces": ["application/json"]
  "paths": {
    "/foo": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "List all foo.",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success.",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Foo"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Foo": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "example": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "An example."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```